# In the following sentences, are the pairs of prepositions 와/과 and 에게, 을/를 and 에게 correct and completely interchangeable, right?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

I have sentence as follows:

> 저는 친구들**과** 연락을 해요   and    저는 친구들**에게** 연락을 해요 (I'm in touch with my friends)
>
> 나는 친구들**을** 도와줬어요    and    나는 친구들**에게** 도와줬어요 (I helped my friends)

In this sentences, are the pairs of prepositions 와/과 and 에게, 을/를 and 에게 correct and completely interchangeable, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the "correct and completely interchangeable" part of your question, no, not completely.

1. 저는 친구들과 연락을 해요 = I **keep** in touch with my friends.
2. 저는 친구들에게 연락을 해요 = I **get** in touch with my friends (i.e. **contact** them).

The two phrases are used interchangeably in many cases, but their main point is a little different. 와/과 연락해요 sounds like two way interaction while 에게 fits one way communication better (might be a small difference but it often matters). So if you're notifying your friend about something, you should use 에게 (e.g. 친구한테/에게 올 필요(가) 없다고 연락했다 / 말했다. 친구와 is strange).  Likewise, if you're contacting the police, you don't say 경찰과 연락했다 but must say 경찰에 연락했다 (use 에 instead of 한테/에게 if the recipient is an organization). 경찰과 연락했다 is not completely wrong but it is a much poorer choice.

1. 나는 친구들을 도와줬어요 = I helped my friends.
2. 나는 친구들에게 도와줬어요 (X).  This is wrong.

도와주다 is a transitive verb taking a direct object.  You can sometimes omit the object but cannot use 에게 in place of 을/를.  It sounds strange.

You can correlate the usage with English.

1. 친구를 돕다 / 도와주다 = help a friend.
2. 친구에게 돕다 / 도와주다 (X) = help to a friend (X)
3. 친구에게 도움을 주다 (O) = provide/give help to a friend (O).
4. 동생이 숙제하는 것을 도와주다 = help my brother with his home work. (the structures don't match up in this case)

#3 uses 에게 because the verb is now 주다 which commonly takes P-에게 N-을 주다 (give N to P). 도와주다 is closer to 돕다 in meaning and grammar, so it can't conjugate like 주다.